# Parsing a json object with an unknown name with gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

```
    {
   "lastUpdated":1404620562,
   "invasions":{
      "Vibrant Valley":{
         "asOf":1404620562,
         "type":"Penny Pincher",
         "progress":"959/1000"
      }
   },
   "error":null
}
```

I'm new to using Json & Gson so be patient. 
So I am attempting to make an application for myself that allows me to view the information from this json file. The only problem is that it is constantly changing and sometimes there will be more then one object under invasions or sometimes there will be none. How would I parse this with gson? Thanks. Note I am grabbing values from here.
https://www.toontownrewritten.com/api/invasions
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `JsonParser` class

```
String myJson =  "{" +
"  \"lastUpdated\":1404620562," +
"  \"invasions\":{" +
"    \"Vibrant Valley\":{" +
"      \"asOf\":1404620562," +
"      \"type\":\"Penny Pincher\"," +
"      \"progress\":\"959/1000\"" +
"    }" +
"  }," +
"  \"error\":null" +
"}"

JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(myJson);
JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
long lastUpdated = jobject.get("lastUpdated").getAsLong();
```